# Изменение количества товара в корзине

Tags: modx, minishop2, jquery, html

Добрый день! Наверное, слишком много и часто пишу тут, но хочется просто получить быстрее решения.
В корзине, как известно, есть регулятор количества покупаемого товара. Выглядит примерно так: [image]

Как заметили, я добавил к стандартному input еще картинки-регуляторы (- и +) по бокам.   Написал такой скрипт на jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.minus').bind('click', function()
  {
    console.log("вошли в минус!");
    var itemNum=$(this).attr('data-extend');
    console.log(itemNum);
    var c = $("#myinput"+itemNum).val();
        c--;
    console.log(c);  
    $("#myinput"+itemNum).val(c);
  });     

  $(".plus").click(function()
  {
    console.log("вошли в плюсик!");
    var itemNum=$(this).attr('data-extend');
    console.log(itemNum);
    var c = $("#myinput"+itemNum).val();
        c++;
    console.log(c);  
    $("#myinput"+itemNum).val(c);
  });    
});
</script>
```

А в чанке `tpl.msCart.row` это представлено таким макаром:

```
<div class="amount-box" style="height: 30px !important;">
      <p class="minus" data-extend="[[+id]]"></p>        
      <input type="number" id="myinput[[+id]]" name="count" value="[[+count]]" max-legth="4" class="input-sm form-control" style="width: 30px; height:20px; outline:none;"/>
      <p class="plus" data-extend="[[+id]]"></p>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="ms2_action" value="cart/change"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></button>
    </div>
```

Когда я изменяю количество товара через стандартные регуляторы поля input, то корзина обновляет изменения и фиксирует их, а когда жму свои нарисованные регуляторы (- и +), то в input изменяется число товара, но в корзине сообщений и изменений никаких нет. Как можно привязать события нажатия по классу minus и plus к реальным изменениям в корзине. Спасибо за ответ, если таковой будет...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В общем вопрос этот решается довольно просто, дописываем в функции клика кнопок:

```
$("#myinput"+itemNum).trigger('submit');
```

И все отлично работает).